# VPN Access to SQL Server from Web Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, vpn

I am setting up a .Net based application on an Internet server and in the same hosting provider data center I am setting up SQL Server.  My desire is to have SQL Server protected through VPN such that only application server can access it. In addition, I should be able to access the database server computer remotely through Remote Desktop Connection from anywhere.  Is this possible?  If yes, will I need to make changes to DB connection string in web.config file of the app?

What other options do I have to protect the database which will be on a server that is connected to the Internet?  Is there a place I can find more information as to how to setup VPN network and configure .Net app to use the database remotely through VPN connection?

Comment: If understood correctly, you are asking about having both  IIS hosting your public webapp and sql server on the same machine (?) and protecting the SQL server. While this is not the preferred mode/architecture it is done routinely for smaller non enterprise apps. 
However your question is very broad. you should probably narrow it down to specific issues as you encounter them

Comment: @danidev no both on separate machines

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could configure your application like that, but it will be hard for you to configure the VPN by yourself, if you're hosting both services in a data center.

So, protecting both services/environments is a matter of firewalls configuration, so that nobody from outside could reach it (I mean FW in data center, not the windows one - so requires some request to the data center admin).

Then, you have to set up a VPN, you can either choose a software VPN (so from the client you will have to run a client to connect - like Windows VPN Client, or Cisco, or ShrewSoft), or a static IPSec, which won't require any client to bring the tunnel up and connect.

Usually in data centers it boils down to asking for some configuration, where you provide source machines, destination and ports for communication in both directions.

Once you have the VPN established, you don't need to change your web app configuration much, probably you will have to change the IP address of the servers (e.g. in the connectionString) as they will probably be seen as local addresses, or totally different behind a NAT.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You gave me an idea. Instead of VPN, I can configure firewall to allow SQL server port to be access from a fix IP address.  Since the other machine that will be hosting the webapp will have an static IP, this should work.

Comment: Sure, if that is what is enough for you, and it's possible within the internal network, why not. Remember that VPN adds encryption of the transferred data and is mainly used if direct connection is not a way to go.